# how to get json data on server side

Tags: c#, .net, json, httpwebrequest

I need to send and receive json data between two web side. 
i am trying send json data with http request. i can send request but i couldnt get json data on other side. i am sending data like on bellow. but i couldnt find this json data on teh other side in Request object.

```
 var webAddr = "http://localhost:3730/Safe2Pay.aspx";
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                TestJason ddd = new TestJason();
                ddd.data1 = "Data1";
                ddd.data2 = "Data2";

                JavaScriptSerializer jsSeri = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                String sb = jsSeri.Serialize(ddd);

                streamWriter.Write(sb);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: Are you not getting the request on the other server or are you getting a request without content?

Comment: i am getting request but i couldnt reach the content. And i dont know how can i reach it ?

Comment: Can you post the receive code from the other server?

Comment: i have two web application on my localhost (http://localhost:21836 and http://localhost:3730) i am sending web request from 21836 to 3730. if send request like form request i can get data on 3730. but i want to send json data. when i send to json data from 21836 to 3730 i cant reach json data in 3730. Please send me an example how to send data in one side and how to recieve data on other side. Maybe i colundt send json succesfuul